# Trying to use WinInet to upload a file to HDFS

Tags: hdfs, wininet, webhdfs

I am using WinInet to try and upload a file to Hadoop.  I am doing everything I can think of correctly.  IOW, I am following the REST API for WebHDFS including getting the re-direct, then sending a new request with the URI provided in the re-direct.  When I make my second request, I can see from spying with Fiddler that it returns an HTTP status code of 201 like it should.

The second request goes something like:

1. Do WinInet stuff necessary to call `HttpOpenRequest()` with a verb of PUT (succeeds)
2. Call `HttpSendRequestEx()` with all NULLs except hRequest (succeeds)
3. Write data to file using `InternetWriteFile()` (succeeds with the correct number of bytes written matching the same as I tried to write)
4. Call `HttpEndRequest()` (succeeds)

Everything succeeds, and by all rights the data should be on the server.  Instead, there is just an empty file.  If I try the same thing using curl, it succeeds.  If I spy on WinInet using Fiddle, I see everything succeeding except I never see the data being written to the server.

The headers being returned after I call HttpEndRequest() are:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 12 Jun 2015 00:22:57 GMT
Date: Fri, 12 Jun 2015 00:22:57 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 12 Jun 2015 00:22:57 GMT
Date: Fri, 12 Jun 2015 00:22:57 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Location: webhdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/test.txt
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(6.1.26.cloudera.4)
```

My gut says there is something messed up in the InternetWriteFile() that I'm doing, but all the return codes and write values check out good.

Are there any tricks to doing a PUT with WinInet that I am missing?